# Managing Lotus Notes Mail Format using C#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am accessing  mail body and fetching it in another mail.
But i am not getting original format of previous mail in new mail.

Problem i am facing in this situation are:

1. Not getting images in destination mail.
2. Font is also varying.

I am accessing mail body as follows:

```
 NotesRichTextItem rtItem = (NotesRichTextItem)docInbox.GetFirstItem("Body");
 String Body = rtItem.GetFormattedText(false , 0);
 String bodyFormat = rtItem.type.ToString();
```

also tried this code:

```
NotesItem itemBody = docInbox.GetFirstItem("Body");
  String bodyFormat = itemBody.type.ToString();
  String Body = itemBody.Text;
```

But not getting solution in both case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to access rich text from Lotus Notes and put it into your own system, that will be very difficult and the NotesAPI is of little help to you.  However, if you are trying to copy a rich text item from one NotesDocument to another, look at the AppendRTItem method of the NotesRichTextItem class.

Comment: Thanx Ken. Can u give me one example of "AppendRTItem"?
How can i use it in my current code ?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation it has examples --> http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2359850.nsf/2e73cbb2141acefa85256b8700688cea/dc72d312572a75818525731b004a5294?OpenDocument